# Testing an Angular app with ngUpgrade fails with "Unknown provider: ng2.InjectorProvider <- ng2.Injector"

Tags: angular, ng-upgrade

I'm trying to use `ngUpgrade` to move from ng1 to ng2, and also keep my Karma/Jasmine tests passing during the upgrade, but I'm running into an error I can't figure out.

I've upgraded a Service (`Data`) to be an ng2 `@Injectable`, and used `upgradeAdapter.downgradeNg2Provider` to inject it into my ng1 app. It works fine in production code.

But when I try to $inject it in my tests, I get this error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ng2.InjectorProvider <- ng2.Injector <- Data
```

**Anyone have a working example of unit testing your code in the middle of ngUpgrade?** My stack is Webpack-based. I tried following and converting the [systemjs guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html#!#preparing-unit-and-e2e-tests) but didn't have any luck.

**karma.conf.js**:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    // base path used to resolve all patterns
    basePath: '',

    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    // list of files/patterns to load in the browser
    files: [{ pattern: 'spec.bundle.js', watched: false }],

    // files to exclude
    exclude: [],

    plugins: [
      require('karma-phantomjs-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-webpack')
    ],

    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: { 'spec.bundle.js': ['webpack'] },

    webpack: require('./webpack.config'),

    webpackServer: {
      noInfo: true // prevent console spamming when running in Karma!
    },

    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],

    // web server port
    port: 9876,

    // enable colors in the output
    colors: true,

    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

    // toggle whether to watch files and rerun tests upon incurring changes
    autoWatch: true,

    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],

    // if true, Karma runs tests once and exits
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

**spec.bundle.js**

```
import 'angular';
import 'angular-mocks';

import 'es6-shim';
import 'reflect-metadata';

import 'angular2/src/core/di';
import test from 'angular2/testing';
import browser from 'angular2/platform/testing/browser';

test.setBaseTestProviders(browser.TEST_BROWSER_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS,
                          browser.TEST_BROWSER_APPLICATION_PROVIDERS);

let context = require.context('./src', true, /\.spec\.js/);

context.keys().forEach(context);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you should not use angular mocks' `module` and `inject` but the `UpgradeProvider`.

It's not documented yet but there are some clues in angular 2's source code.

1. Your `UpgradeAdapter` instance should be a singleton.
2. You should add your providers to the `UpgradeAdapter` singleton using `UpgradeAdapter.addProvider`.
3. You should start the app using `UpgradeAdapter.bootstrap` then grab the `UpgradeAdapterRef` instance given to `ready`'s callback function.
4. Get the `ng1Injector` attribute from the `UpgradeAdapterRef` instance.
5. Instantiate your service using the injector's synchronuous `get` method.

Here's a plunker with the solution:
https://embed.plnkr.co/EauYut/

We also published a blog post about angular 2 migration on Wishtack. We will soon be filling the blog with more posts about angular 2 testing.

http://www.blog.wishtack.com/#!AngularJS-vs-Angular-2-Should-I-Stay-or-Should-I-Go/cuhk/573b59710cf233ef713771b2

Hope it helps